# MergingPersistenceUnitManager

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have recently found your reply in a topic about using multiple persistence.xml files from multi module project. You said something about MergingPersistenceUnitManager. Could you please tell me where can I find it ? The link you provided seems not to work.

Comment: There is no such class in Spring.

Comment: That's right, but Oliver Gierke wrote something about his open source project which includes this class.

Comment: OK. The solution is here: http://ancientprogramming.blogspot.com/2007/05/multiple-persistencexml-files-and.html :)

Comment: You're right, I mentioned it here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748377/how-do-you-make-a-multi-module-spring-configuration/780737#780737) answering a question regarding application modularity with Spring. The class we wrote is pretty much the same as in the link you provided there but is not open source yet.