# Extending spring based app

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-ws

I have a spring-based Web Service. I now want to build a sort of plugin for it that extends it with beans. What I have now in web.xml is:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/*-configuration.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My core app has `main-configuration.xml` which declares its beans. My plugin app has `plugin-configuration.xml` which declares additional beans. Now when I deploy, my build deploys `plugin.jar` into `/WEB-INF/lib/` and copies `plugin-configuration.xml` into `/WEB-INF/classes/` all under `main.war`.

This is all fine (although I think there could be a better solution), but when I develop the plugin, I don't want to have two projects in Eclipse with dependencies. I wish to have `main.jar` that I include as a library. However, `web.xml` from `main.jar` isn't automatically discovered. How can I do this? Bean injection? Bean discovery of some sort? Something else?

Note: I expect to have multiple different plugins in production, but development of each of them will be against pure main.jar

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a simpler approach:

In your host application (the webapp) define something like the following `contextConfigLocation` parameter:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath*:/META-INF/foo/*-configuration.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The crucial parts are `classpath*:`as it results in scanning the entire classpath for config files matching the following pattern. If you only use `classpath:` the lookup will stop at the first file found. It also won't traverse JARs if not starred correctly.

The second crucial part is having at least one non-wildcarded basepath for the lookup to work. This is due to `Classloader` traits that only reliably returns all resources if they contain a base path (see the [Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html) on `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` for details).

What you now have to do with your plugin projects is place your `plugin-configuration.xml` in `/META-INF/foo/`, package that as JAR and place it into your classpath (in case you build with Maven just add the dependency).

On application start Spring will now also pickup all config files from your plugins and build the ÀpplicationContext` from em.

You also might wanna checkout another post I did on application modularity with Spring: [How do you make a multi-module spring configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748377/how-do-you-make-a-multi-module-spring-configuration/780737#780737)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `/WEB-INF/classes/*-configuration.xml`, try `classpath:*-configuration.xml`
You can also list configuration files, each on a new line.

You will have to make sure that main.jar ends up in WEB-INF/lib, if you're not using maven you can do this in eclipse by marking you webapp as dependent on the project that creates the main.jar, via the project properties.